# Cannot connect to VM from Windows 10

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I've created a basic VM in Azure. I've downloaded the RDP file and it keeps saying login attempt failed.

The RDP port is definitely open as I have connected to it via Telnet.

I've tried username as

vmname\vmuser

vmuser

\vmuser

What is a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the username or password you are using for the VM is incorrect. You can use the password reset function in the portal on the VM blade to reset it.